# How to compare two columns with thousands of rows

Tags: excel, compare

I need a quick help please. I have two columns in excel with thousands of rows. They are supposed to be the same, that is a1 =b1, a2 =b2, a3=b3 and so on. But i need to confirm that is in fact true. So how do i verify that quickly without having to create a third column of thousands of rows. (several ways that i discarded are using the "=and(exact..." formula or color coding where there are differences. Because those methods would again require me to check the new third row or check all the rows manually for color difference). The values in the rows that i have are alphanumeric.I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have just seen a very similar thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713179/trying-to-compare-two-xcel-reports-for-heading-changes) suggesting using an [**Array Formula**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/create-an-array-formula-HP005200020.aspx). You would need to enter the formula below and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, you can tell it is being handled as an array formula if curly braces are shown around it when you go back to the cell:

```
=AND(Sheet1!A1:A10000=Sheet2!B1:B10000)
```

Note that the ranges in the formula above can be adjusted as required, I have assumed from your question that 10k rows will be enough to compare and that you want to compare column A in sheet1 to column B in sheet2.

Comment: simplified from `=if(AND(Sheet1!A1:A10000=Sheet2!B1:B10000),True,False)` to `=AND(Sheet1!A1:A10000=Sheet2!B1:B10000)`

Comment: Thank you Chris, it worked like a charm. And my rows were nearly 1/4 million rows. But it worked so thank you.